# Transform complex json files using ADF

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I want to transform multiple complex JSON files into one complex JSON file using Azure Data Factory dataflow.

The multiple complex input JSON files are in the following format:

```json
{
  "creationDate": "2022-01-19T17:00:17Z",
  "count": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "name": "Project A",
      "url": "",
      "state": "Open",
      "revision": 1,
      "visibility": "private",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2019-09-23T08:44:45.103Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "name": "Project B",
      "url": "",
      "state": "Done",
      "revision": 1,
      "visibility": "private",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2019-12-31T09:38:49.16Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

We want to transform those files to one single json file in the format:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022-01-14",
    "count": 2,
    "projects": [
      {
        "name": "Project A",
        "state": "",
        "lastUpdateTime": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Project B",
        "state": "",
        "lastUpdateTime": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-01-17",
    "count": 3,
    "projects": [
      {
        "name": "Project A",
        "state": "",
        "lastUpdateTime": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Project B",
        "state": "",
        "lastUpdateTime": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Project C",
        "state": "",
        "lastUpdateTime": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

We were using the derived column with the expression `@(name=data.name, state=data.state)`.
[image]

Can someone help us how to do this? We tried a lot of things like derived column, first flattening but we can't get it as we like...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution on the end was pretty close on what we had.

So our final solution is as follow:

1. First `flatten` with `Unroll by` set to `data`. We also mapped the `creationDate` to `date`.
2. Create a `derived column` called `projects` with as expression `@(name=name,state=state,lastUpdateTime=lastUpdateTime,url=url)`
3. `Group` activity with a `Group by` on `date`. Set `Aggregates` for `count` on `first(count)` and (this was the solution) set `projects` to `collect(projects)`.
4. `Select` activity which will select the columns `date`, `count` and `projects`.
5. `Sort` activity with a sort on `date` Ascending.
6. Sink with `file name option` to `output to single file` and `partion option` set to `single partion`

**Note:**
Because we have a sink to one big json file (output to single file). The sorting wasn't correct written to json. If we debugged (data preview) the dataflow everything was correct. Strange behavior. When we changed the `Sort` activity the option `Partion option` to `Single partion` the json file had the right sort order.

[image]